# Is there a way to reformat equation to get unknown variable from formula?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, physics, equation

I am making an app where I want to work with formulas/equations from math and physics. I included a calculator section to each formula, so that user is able to insert his values and get the result of equation. The problem is, that I need to reformat equations for each unknown variable, is there a script, or at least somekind of algorithm that is able to do this?

I am using a MathJax react-native module to display expressions, and javascript `eval` function to evaluate them.
I found algebra.js plugin but that doesn't seem to contain any of things I need, same as "nerdamer" js plugin on github.

I use this function to evaluate equation, `variable_finding` is the variable on "left side" of equation, the rest of the code is taking care of  "right side"

```
calculateSolution = (variable_finding) => {
  equation = this.state.input_equation
  vars = []

  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.variables.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.variables[i].variable !=
      variable_finding.variable) {
      vars.push([
        this.state.variables[i].variable,
        '£' + this.state.variables[i].variable + '£',
        this.state.variables[i].value
      ])
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    equation = equation.replace(vars[i][1], vars[i][2]);
  }

  this.setState({
    solution: equation,
  })
}
```

I'd like to find some solution/function, so that I'll be able to input a equation with variables, then choose one variable and the function will create a new equation, so that the selected variable will be on left side of equation and the rest will be on right side.

Comment: Do you want a general solution which could handle any equation, or do you want it to operate on a restricted set of equations, say polynomials? The smaller the set of inputs the more tractable it becomes.

Comment: Sure, general solution would be better, but as I am trying to do mostly high school stuff, quadratic/cubic equations should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving equations for a given variable is a very complex problem.
What you're looking for is essentially a [`CAS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) for javascript.

If you don't mind solving the equation on the server, you could use one of the freely available CAS's (click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) for a list)
In MATLAB for example you can use [`solve(eq, var)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) to solve for a specific variable.

In terms of pure javascript implementations, you could use [`coffeequate`](https://coffeequate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```js
let equation = CQ("E = m*(c**2)");

let solutions = equation.solve("c");
for(let solution of solutions)
  console.log("c =", solution.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/coffeequate@1.3.0/coffeequate.min.js"></script>
```

Please note though that `coffeequate` can't solve all types of equations.

You can also get rid of your `eval` with it by using [`toFunction`](https://coffeequate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#converting-to-functions):

```js
let expression = CQ("a + b**c");
let fn = expression.toFunction("a", "b", "c");
console.log("1 + 2**3 =", fn(1, 2, 3).toString()); // 9
console.log("3 + 2**1 =", fn(3, 2, 1).toString()); // 5
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/coffeequate@1.3.0/coffeequate.min.js"></script>
```

Additionally you can also use it to [simplify / expand](https://coffeequate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#simplifying-expressions) equations, if you need that functionality:

```js
let eqStr = "(x + y)*(x - y)";
let equation = CQ(eqStr);
console.log(eqStr, "===", equation.simplify().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/coffeequate@1.3.0/coffeequate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your responser looks great, I consider that as a best solution of my problem. I think I'll to cooperate with server and I'll force users to be online if they're going to use calculate functions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we are just dealing with quadratic equations like

```
y = a x^2 + b x + c
```

Then there is an explicit solution from the quadratic formula.

```
x = ( -b +/- sqrt( b^2 - 4 * a * (c-y)) / 2 a.
```

To implement this you would need a parser for the equation, using something like 
the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.

Once parsed you can manipulate the parse tree, extract the constants a, b, c, and evaluate the formula.

Cubics is much harder. There is a formula but its nasty.